# How did the Tauntaun's guts keep Luke warm on Hoth?

Tags: star-wars

When Han Solo finally finds Luke on Hoth, he uses Luke's lightsaber to slice open the Tauntaun. He then proceeds to rub the guts of the Tauntaun on Luke telling him that it will keep him warm. Now I know that the guts would be warm at first since it was a living creature, but he says that it will "keep" him warm until the shelter is built. Is there some sort of insulation factor that the guts have?

Comment: I think this might help you; http://www.choosy-beggars.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/tauntaun.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He doesn't just rub the guts on him, he stuffs him inside the dead tauntaun. Not only would the beast's residual bodyheat have helped, but the tauntaun also has natural insulation that would have kept Luke warm.

From http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html

> Han ignites Luke's saber and cuts the beast from head to toe.  He 
>   quickly tosses it's steaming innards into the snow, then lifts Luke's 
>   inert form and stuffs him inside the carcass.

Comment: Mythbusters covered this in there recent Star Wars special and came the same conclusions it would have worked quite well to be stuffed into a recently dead tautaun.

Comment: @draksia - which one of them was the "lucky" one stuffed inside a dead cow?

Comment: The simulator from the titanic myth not a real person, I guess no one wanted to test hypothermia in a fake tauntaun.

Comment: Mythbusters killed a Tauntaun just for their TV show? Man, that's f'd up.